# Strange CFNetwork crash in iOS7.1 - possibly AFNetworking Related

Tags: ios, crash, afnetworking, ios7.1, cfnetwork

I have started receiving details of a crash that I have not seen before, and it only appears to have started happening since the 7.1 update.

The exact line from the stack is :

```
CFNetwork   
___ZN14CoreStreamBase34_streamSetEventAndScheduleDeliveryEmh_block_invoke + 30
```

and the entire trace is here:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a1b81f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a222797 pthread_kill + 58
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x3a168fdd abort + 76
3  libc++abi.dylib                0x39497cd7 abort_message + 74
4  libc++abi.dylib                0x394af6f3 __cxa_pure_virtual + 18
5  CFNetwork                      0x2ec994bf ___ZN14CoreStreamBase34_streamSetEventAndScheduleDeliveryEmh_block_invoke + 30
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2ef37981 CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
7  CFNetwork                      0x2ec007fb RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 182
8  CFNetwork                      0x2ec006b9 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 220
9  CFNetwork                      0x2ec0054d MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2efcf25b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2efce72b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2efccf1f __CFRunLoopRun + 622
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2ef37f4f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2ef37d33 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
15 GraphicsServices               0x33e3e663 GSEventRunModal + 138
16 UIKit                          0x3188316d UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

The only other thread i can see that is running is from AFNetworking, as this would be the only thing I would imagine is using CFNetworking:

```
Thread : AFNetworking (com.apple.main-thread)
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a1a5a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3a1a5859 mach_msg + 48
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2efce89b __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 154
3  CoreFoundation                 0x2efccfc1 __CFRunLoopRun + 784
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2ef37f4f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2ef37d33 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
6  Foundation                     0x2f92a1eb -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
7  Foundation                     0x2f97b0a1 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
8  ****                           0x0011d35f +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:148)
9  Foundation                     0x2f9eca5f __NSThread__main__ + 1062
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a221919 _pthread_body + 140
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a22188b _pthread_start + 102
```

Has anyone else experienced issues with this? I have been over to the AFN github but cant see anyone else reporting this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Do you got any solution? Please share if there is a fix for this crash.

Comment: Hi - slightly late reply but I ended up removing AFNetworking and this bug continued. This hasn't happened on iOS8 however.